# Rails formhelper with bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Say I have this basic formhelper code:

```
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name, 'Username' %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email, 'Email (Optional)' %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

I know I can change the class of the entire thing by adding an `:html => { :class => "class_name"}` to the form_for arguments, but what about if I want to put each pair of controls in a `form-group` class, and then have the labels have the class `control-label` and the inputs have class `form-control`? Because that's the only way bootstrap will agree to style my forms for me. I tried just throwing html code around the labels and text fields, but it was a monstrosity. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

inb4 form builder gem, I'm learning here, and I keep reading that the ones for rails 4 and bootstrap 3 are still a bit lacking

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can just do `:class => "classname"` as an attribute on the form control ruby commands as well. Way less ugly than endless nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to format a form in Bootstrap is below, using Rails syntax. It may seem unnecessary at first glance, but `div.form-group` is helpful in adding a bit of margin between each pair, as well as giving you a parent to add [validation classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) to.

`.control-label` is generally unnecessary, though if you are going to add those validation classes, you will need to add it to the labels if you want them to change color, as well. `:class => 'control-label'` on the `f.label` is how you add those.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, 'Username' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email (Optional)' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```